# What does (whatever)* construct mean in Git manual pages?

Tags: git, unix

When reading the [git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files), I encountered `()` for several times but I couldn't find a documentation for its meaning.

For example

```
git ls-files [-z] [-t] [-v]
                (--[cached|deleted|others|ignored|stage|unmerged|killed|modified])*
                (-[c|d|o|i|s|u|k|m])*
                [--eol]
                [-x <pattern>|--exclude=<pattern>]
                [-X <file>|--exclude-from=<file>]
                [--exclude-per-directory=<file>]
                [--exclude-standard]
                [--error-unmatch] [--with-tree=<tree-ish>]
                [--full-name] [--abbrev] [--] [<file>…​]
```

I have done some learning and know `<>` is for mandatory arg, `[]` for optional and `{}`for optional but limited list of choice. But what does `()` means above?

Sorry for this basic question but it's hard to describe and google the answers. A link to the tutorial will be appreciated.

Comment: `()` are parentheses -- braces are `{}`

Comment: Sorry for this confusion... I thought `()` is called brace and `{}` is called curly brace. I have updated the title. Thanks:)

Comment: It's not something I've seen in other man pages, but I expect that `(...)*` means zero or more of whatever is inside the parentheses.

Comment: @msandiford: that's the correct answer, you should probably post it as an answer rather than just a comment...

Comment: normally `[]` means *optional* and `()` means *required*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not something I've seen in other man pages, but I expect that `(...)*` means zero or more of whatever is inside the parentheses.

I'm reliably informed that this is the case. Thanks @torek

Comment: Thanks! It looks like the git documentation adopts some regex syntax.